# Laravel RelationShip Selecting Fileds Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i'm trying to get properties from the relationship between tables , but its seems not working , i tried other solution in the web but still not working , here the code bellow that i call :

```
$data = Employer::with(['contratClient'=>function($query){$query->select("idcontrat");}])
                ->where("id_entre",1)
                ->get();
echo "<pre>";
dd($data[0]->contratClient);
echo "</pre>";
```

the Employer Model :

```
class Employer extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_em';
    protected $table = 'employers';
    protected $guarded = array();

    public function contratClient(){
         return $this->hasMany("App\ContratClient","id_emp");
    }
 }
```

the ContratClient Model :

```
class ContratClient extends Model
{
     protected $primaryKey = 'idcontrat';
     protected $table = 'contratClients';

     public function employer(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Employer','id_em');
     }
}
```

here is the result:

[image]

if i miss any thing please i'm listing , still a beginner in Laravel

thanks

Comment: Do you have any result in $data? If you do, Are there any records in your Contrat_clients table with the id_em as the id of the first element?

Comment: What is the foreign key in the contratClients table, `id_em` or `id_emp`?

Comment: @dparoli its id_emp

Comment: try this: return $this->belongsTo('App\Employer','id_emp');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The models relationships should be:

```
class Employer extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_em';
    protected $table = 'employers';
    protected $guarded = array();

    public function contratClient(){
         return $this->hasMany("App\ContratClient","id_emp", "id_em");
    }
}

class ContratClient extends Model
{
     protected $primaryKey = 'idcontrat';
     protected $table = 'contratClients';

     public function employer(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Employer','id_emp', 'id_em');
     }
}
```

To verify relationships, try first to get rows with that:

```
$data = Employer::with('contratClient')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your primary keys are not what laravel would require. For example :

In `employers` table, laravel would need `employer_id` but your primary key is `id_em`. Please update your relationships to following and check again :

```
class Employer extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_em';
    protected $table = 'employers';
    protected $guarded = array();

    public function contratClient(){

         return $this->hasMany('App\ContratClient','foreign_key_in_this_table', 'idcontrat');
    }
 }

class ContratClient extends Model
{
     protected $primaryKey = 'idcontrat';
     protected $table = 'contratClients';

     public function employer(){

         return $this->belongsTo('App\Employer','foreign_key_in_this_table', 'id_em');
     }
}
```

Also just checking if it's a type `contratClients` and did you mean `contractClients` ?